# DocumentClient query returns invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

I am trying to query my dynamodb table for a specific partition_key in which the sort key begins with "REFRESHTOKEN_". I am using DocumentClient query operation for this. When ran, I get the following error message that the expression attribute :refreshTokenID is not defined when clearly it is. See below for what my query looks like.

```
 var queryParams = {
            TableName: 'security',
            KeyConditionExpression: 'partition_key=:refreshTokenID and begins_with(sort_key, :refreshTokenString)',
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{
                ':refreshTokenID': refreshToken.refreshTokenID,
                ':refreshTokenString': 'REFRESHTOKEN'
            }
        };

        var data = await dynamodb_driver.query('us-east-1', queryParams);
```

Comment: Have you checked that 'refreshToken.refreshTokenID' is not null/undefined?

Comment: You are correct, the refreshTokenID was null and therefore the field ':refreshTokenID' was omitted altogether. Did not realize that was the behavior as I expected the null value to atleast be passed through.